Can I get securities from a certain exchange, then filter them through loops & conditions to then list them on the chart?
I've went through the documentation & also have searched for the functions available but can't seem to find something that works for my logic. Have also tried using AI but can't be 100% sure due to it's hallucinations.
I basically wanted to in a way create a screener. Since some conditions are not available under the normal screener I am planning to filter it through code & draw on the chart.
Is it possible to: Get securities from exchange X > Loop > Filter > Draw on chart.
Second step onwards should be doable, but I'm having trouble with the first step.
Thanks.

No, that is currently not possible with Pine Script. There are few older questions about this topic. What I do: I use a Python script as a scanner which connects to the broker. Then, I have a dashboard with my criteria and I enter the symbols manually. Far from perfect, but I got used to it.

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.
